# What is the reason behind closing the village/street/agrahara temple in case of a death in the nearby area?

Tags: temple, dharma-shastras, agamas, customs

I have seen this several times, that temples are closed if there is a death in the houses in the vicinity. To clarify, vicinity has a variable scope here; sometimes it's a street, sometimes an agrahara or maybe a small village.

What is the reason for the closure? Which dharmasastras and/or agamas give more details on it?